# Core-data many-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, many-to-many

I have an Android app, and now I'm making an iOS version, but I'm having some problem with the joins in CoreData.

I have the following tables:

```
Cidade
    -cid_codigo integer primary key
    -cid_nome text
    -cid_nome_normalizado text

Anunciante
    -anu_codigo integer primary key
    -anu_nome text
    -some other values

AnuncianteCidade
    -cid_codigo integer
    -anu_codigo integer
```

To get the all data from table Cidade I use the following method:

```
+(NSMutableArray *)getAllCidades{
    NSMutableArray *retorno = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Cidade" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    //WHERE CLAUSE
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"1 = 1"];
    [request setPredicate:pred];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *cidades = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if([cidades count] == 0){
        NSLog(@"Nenhuma cidade encontrada");
    }else{
        for(NSManagedObject *cidade in cidades){
            Cidade *c = [[Cidade alloc] init];
            [c initWithCodigo:[[cidade valueForKey:@"cid_codigo"] integerValue] nome:[cidade valueForKey:@"cid_nome"] nomeNormalizado:[cidade valueForKey:@"cid_nome_normalizado"]];
            [retorno addObject:c];
        }
    }

    return retorno;
}
```

But now, given a name from Cidade, I want to get all the data from Anunciante associated with this Cidade.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Core Data is not a database.  Core Data is an object graph that happens to persist to disk and one of the formats that Core Data can persist to is a database structure.  This is an important distinction that will help you to work with it moving forward.

First, you cannot call just `-init` on a `NSManagedObject`.  That will not work as it is not the designated initializer of `NSManagedObject`.  I would suggest you read up on Core Data and learn how to stand up the Core Data stack.

Having said that, your `Cidade` objects should have a reference to `Anunciante`.  The join table is internal to Core Data and you don't have access to it nor should you.  To get all of the `Anunciante` objects for a `Cidade` object is to simply request the objects:

Given an `NSArray` of `Cidade` objects:

```
NSArray *objects = ...;
for (NSManagedObject *object in objects) {
  NSSet *anunciantes = [object valueForKey:@"anunciante"];
}
```

This is assuming you have a many to many relationship defined in the Core Data model editor between the `Cidade` and the `Anunciante` entities.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `NSSet* anunciantes ...`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Marcus' answer, I would add that a predicate `"1 = 1"` could be simply left out.

To insert a managed object into the context you use a `NSEntityDescription` class method:

```
Cidade *cidade = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Cidade" 
      inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

All "anunciantes" of a cidade will be conveniently available to you as a `NSSet`:

```
cidade.anunciantes
```

is all you need.